# how to develop Super Apps using MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit

one of our POC requirements is to develop a Super Mobile App, which should download mini apps on demand.

Questions

1. Can we dynamically load mini apps (dlls) into a .Net Maui Shell app on demand? is this even possible using Maui native or hybrid ?

and in the future maybe a App Center where anyone can publish their mini apps into it.

Comment: Technically doable but you could not publish such app in googleplay or appstore though, it's against their rules.

Comment: Side-loading is reserved for app stores and system apps. Your client app won't be able to do such a thing as a regular app that you push to the stores.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share something similar I have done for Android.

I have this KIOSK App, that plays the role of Device Owner, that can be only installed after Factory Reset, and following the provisioning procedure.

You do not need the Store, all you need is QR code with a link to download the app.
That application has its own store. And thanks to its elevated permissions, it can download them and even install them, without user interaction or need for permissions. (In fact, it can grant permissions to self or other apps, without user interaction either).

Business logic resides in the other Applications, that are getting downloaded. The main Device Owner is nothing but a way to manage them.

So, check:

1. Device Owner application
2. Provisioning
3. Package Installer

We are talking about platform specific code here.